# How to convert px to % (within 100%) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, math, input, range

I have a little problem and I would be very grateful to any answers.

In general, there's upload of image in my code, and there's input which changes its height.

HTML code:

```
<p>Height</p>
            
<input type='range' min='1' max='100' step='1' value='30' class='range' />
```

And here's the JS code which works when image just uploaded:

```
const image = document.querySelector('.image')
range.value = image.height
```

JS code of changing the height:

```
const range = document.querySelector('.range')

range.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
  let x = range.value
  let color = 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0,0,0)' + x + '%, rgb(159, 159, 159)' + x + '%)'
  range.style.background = color
  image.style.height = range.value + '%'
})
```

The problem is that when addEventListener works first time, it takes range.value, and this value is the height of image (for example, 121px), and this height is more than 100, but input's "max" attribute is equal to 100 (max="100), so value of input changes to 100, and image's too. I mean, height of image is 100% now, which shouldn't be.

SO, how can I take image's height (121px) and convert it to percents, but within 100%, so I could use this number to set input's value attribute first time?

Comment: why not simply set `max` to `121` (image's height)?

Comment: Because user can upload image with different height

Comment: why not simply set `max` to image's height?

Comment: Because it should be 100 so background would change as the height changes

Comment: how background related to a range's value?

Comment: Check the code, the gradient uses X variable which is actually range's value

Comment: If you know how to make changing background (like progress bar you know) other way, I would like to see it :)

Comment: oh miss that, but it's simple fix `let x = range.value/range.max` :)

Comment: I'm bad at math honestly but I don't see any logic here, even though I tried it and it doesn't work, but maybe I just got your point wrong, like, can you explain why it should work?

Comment: ah, sorry my bad, you need to *100. `let x = range.value/range.max*100`

Comment: and `image.style.height = x + '%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that **max** attribute should be the same as input's width, like, if input.clientWidth is 200px, then is could be done like that: input.max = input.clientWidth. It is not really related to question, but worked for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the relative value by getting `window.height` and finding the ratio between them. If you want to find a real implementation, please set up a jsfiddle so I can work on it.

Comment: You mean something like that? - http://jsfiddle.net/tmxg61yk/6/
I tried it, but I need a number within 100

Comment: Is this what you are expecting: https://jsfiddle.net/a6mL9qp7/